# Почему не работает правило SQL запроса?

Tags: sql

Собственно SQL запрос:

```
SELECT a.id, a.postId, a.creatorId, a.targetId, a.groupId, a.text, a.content,
      a.app, a.access, a.created, a.publishedByTitle, a.publishedByDate, a.publishedPostId
  FROM activities a, friends f, groupmembers gm, groups g WHERE

  (a.creatorId IN (SELECT F.friendTwoId FROM friends F, users U WHERE
    F.friendOneId = 1 AND F.friendTwoId = U.uid)
  ) OR 
  (
  a.creatorId IN (SELECT F.friendOneId FROM friends F, users U WHERE
    F.friendOneId = U.uid AND F.friendTwoId = 1 AND F.status = 1)
  )
  OR
  (a.groupId IN (SELECT g.gid FROM groups g, groupmembers gm
                        WHERE g.gid in(SELECT groupId FROM groupmembers WHERE memberId = 1)
                        AND g.gid = gm.groupId
                        GROUP BY g.gid)
  )

  AND a.id < 10
  AND a.creatorId <> 1
  GROUP BY a.id
  ORDER BY a.created DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

Не работает правило `AND a.id < 10`, никакой реакции. Выводит все, даже где id больше 10

Comment: Потому что приоритет операции OR ниже чем у AND, и ваш `AND a.id < 10` стал относится только к последнему блоку после последнего OR. То же касается условия `AND a.creatorId <> 1`.

Comment: у вас запрос вида `someCondition OR a.id < 10`, т.е. когда срабатывает someCondition, то a.id не проверяется, поэтому может быть любым. Скорее всего, вам достаточно будет ваши условия вида `(a.creatorId IN (...)) OR (a.creatorId IN (...)) OR...` обернуть в скобки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите группу условий, объединенных оператором `OR`, в круглые скобки

```
SELECT a.id, a.postId, a.creatorId, a.targetId, a.groupId, a.text, a.content,
      a.app, a.access, a.created, a.publishedByTitle, a.publishedByDate, a.publishedPostId
  FROM activities a, friends f, groupmembers gm, groups g WHERE
  (
    (a.creatorId IN (SELECT F.friendTwoId FROM friends F, users U
                     WHERE F.friendOneId = 1 AND F.friendTwoId = U.uid)
    )
    OR 
    (a.creatorId IN (SELECT F.friendOneId FROM friends F, users U
                    WHERE F.friendOneId = U.uid AND F.friendTwoId = 1 AND F.status = 1)
    )
    OR
    (a.groupId IN (SELECT g.gid FROM groups g, groupmembers gm
                   WHERE g.gid in(SELECT groupId FROM groupmembers WHERE memberId = 1)
                        AND g.gid = gm.groupId
                        GROUP BY g.gid)
    )
  )
  AND a.id < 10
  AND a.creatorId <> 1
  GROUP BY a.id
  ORDER BY a.created DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: спасибо помогло